# Am I able to add an auto-installed version of Maven to the Path of a Jenkins Job?

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am trying to see if this is possible.  I have a Jenkins server, which has Maven installation files locally. It works very well where the version of Maven will be installed to the agent as configured by the job.  I can run Maven projects just fine with this.  I am happy with this setup, as Jenkins can install the version of Maven needed by the job without needing to pre-install on the Agent machines.

Now, I have another job which uses Node / NPM to create an NPM package.  I would like the same content to be packaged in a JAR so the resources can be used in our Java applications as well (the content of the package is binary resources... no Java classes / etc).  I've been able to use an NPM resource called maven-deploy, which allows me to generate a JAR file at the same time as creating the TGZ for NPM, using the same version number, etc.  This NPM plugin just makes calls to "mvn" in order to use deploy:deploy-file to deploy a file to a Maven Repository.  Which is what I am after (and it works locally like a treat).

However, when I try to incorporate this into a Freestyle Jenkins Job, I don't seem to be able to just add the auto-installed maven to the path for the workspace / job.  I was hoping that by running the NPM build, using the NPM task, the Jenkins job could be configured to say "put Maven (Version x) on the classpath" so then other tasks have maven available.  Kind of similar to what the Node / NPM Jenkins Plugin does.

Is this possible?  I'm struggling to find it.  Yes, I can add an "Invoke Maven Target" build step, but that's not really what I'd like to do in this case.

As an added degree of difficulty, it would also be good if the Maven Settings file I have defined in Jenkins (and use with the stock-standard Maven build jobs / steps) could also be configured as "available", as that has the credentials needed to deploy to my maven repository.

Comment: I can't follow the whole explanation as I don't use npm,but have you looked at [com.seovic.maven.plugins:npm-maven-plugin](https://github.com/aseovic/npm-maven-plugin)?

Comment: Thanks Ian.  That plugin would be useful if Maven was the driving build tool.  My situation is the reverse: it's already using NPM at the moment, and I was hoping that I wouldn't have to re-write the package.json to get it to fit into the Maven lifecycle.  It's more that there is an NPM task that wants to call out to Maven for its deploy:deploy-file goal, as it doesn't want to use Maven to build / package the content, just deploy.  The suggested Maven plugin could work, but I'd have to refactor the package.json more than I was hoping. But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, I am unable to have a job which just adds Maven to the path of the job.  What I have done, though, in case anyone cares...

In my existing build step where I was using NPM to build the package, I added an extra command which creates an equivalent JAR file.  The build task leverages the [maven-deploy NPM plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/maven-deploy) to package into a JAR file...

[image]

So I can ensure that the Maven artifact is deployed using the same Version Number, I use some bash to persist the version number from package.json into a properties file, which I can then add back into the job as environment variables

[image]

At this point I can just run an Invoke Maven Targets job (although, I had to add a relatively empty and pointless pom.xml file to my code base).  This allows me to use a self-installed Maven installation, as well as my settings which has the credentials needed for deploying...

[image]
[image]

This will work.  I mean, if I could have just added maven to the path, I could have replaced most of that with an extra npm command to do the deploy.  But, there you go

Comment: Perhaps I could have done this cleaner using a Pipeline, but I'm not versed in that lore yet.